# How to set value of age textbox by using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="text" name="age" value="" enabled="false">` paired with a `<input type="date" name="birthdate">
```

I want to set the age text box value as the difference of the present date and the date the user has inputted to automatically get the date using either javascript or jquery

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: Maybe moment.js can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 'vanilla' JS. Then you can parse the date which has been inputted in the DOB.

```
function setAge(e){
  var bday = new Date(Date.parse(e.target.value));
  var today = new Date()
  document.getElementsByName('age')[0].value = today.getFullYear() - bday.getFullYear();
}
```

You can setup an onchange event for the birthday input.

```
<input type="date" name="birthdate" onchange="setAge(event)">
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j4dotd9d/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: this one worked but I was hoping on taking my age when I haven't had my birthday yet still thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

make two small changes in your markup

```
<input type="text" name="age" value="" disabled="true" id="age"> //observe that i have replaced enabled=false  
<input type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate"> //observe that i have given an id attribute to it
```

now you can get the age in year as

```
var date = new Date();
var birthdate = new Date( document.getElementById( "birthdate" ).value );
alert( "age is " + ( date.getFullYear() - birthdate.getFullYear() ) );
```

set this value to the age textbox

```
document.getElementById( "age" ).value = date.getFullYear() - birthdate.getFullYear() ;
```

a simpler jquery version would be

```
var date = new Date();
var birthdate = new Date( $( "#birthdate" ).val() );
var age = date.getFullYear() - birthdate.getFullYear();
$( "age" ).val( age ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can calculate age on change of birth date selected by user. Take difference between time and then calculate year and month .
Note - calculated year and month are approximate, OP should change code accordingly.

```js
$(function(){
  var calculateAge = function(time){
    var months = Math.round(time/(24*60*60*1000*30));
    //alert(months);
    var years = parseInt(months / 12);
    //alert(years);
    months = months % 12;
    return years +" yrs and " + months + " months";
  };

  $('input[name="birthdate"]').change(function(){
       var birthDate = new Date($(this).val()).getTime();
       var presentDate = new Date().getTime();
       //alert(birthDate);
       //alert(presentDate);
       var age = presentDate - birthDate;
       $('input[name="age"]').val(calculateAge(age));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="age" value="" enabled="false"> 
<br/>paired with a <input type="date" name="birthdate">
```

Answer (score 0):

this below code will work just by using year not with month and date please rewrite it

here is the HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="age" value=""/>
<input type="date" id="current" onchange="javaScript:age()"/>
```

here is the javaScript

```
function age() {
var curr = document.getElementById('current').value;
var split = curr.split("-", 1);
var newsplit = parseInt(split);
var date = new Date();
var newcurr= parseInt(date.getFullYear());
var age = newcurr - newsplit;
document.getElementById('age').setAttribute('value', age);
}
```

Comment: dude I have a question though, I wanted to make the age null whenever the age is < 18 for women and <21 for men, Im trying to make a wedding age validation and I tried to make an if condition of if(age <18){
alert("female is no legal age for wedding");}

but as I've noticed it just shows that whenever I am picking a date less than the 18th day :/